# create an explanation of a table in R

Tags: r, latex

i have a latex table generated inside a PDF from an R data frame after a statistical test , i want to create a summary of this table that explain what are the significant variables inside it. how this can be done ??

that's the table :

```
  \hline
 & a & b & c & d & e \\ 
  \hline
a & 1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 \\ 
  b & 0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 0.08 & 0.40 \\ 
  c & 0.00 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  d & 0.00 & 0.08 & 0.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 \\ 
  e & 0.02 & 0.40 & 0.00 & 0.99 & 1.00 \\ 
   \hline
```

Note : significant varaibles are variables that have a value bigger than 0.7 , e.g (d and e have a value =0.99 ) they are signifcant. i want the summary to be as text under the table (e.g the variables d and e are significantly similar | a and e are "weakly similar" (0.02)  T is even less similar with C) , and i want to put * on significant numbers , and the numbers came from a data frame in R

thanks in advance

Comment: What constitutes a significant variable? What form does the summary take? Is it text, is it another table, do you want to bold / italicize / put an * next to the significant numbers? Where do the numbers that go into the table come from?

Comment: @Chase : significant varaibles are variables that have a value bigger than 0.7 , e.g (d and e have a value =0.99 ) they are signifcant.
i want the summary to be as text under the table (e.g the variables d and e are significantly similar | a and e are "weakly similar" (0.02) wrt T and even less similar wrt C) , and i want to put * on significant numbers , and the numbers came from a data frame in R , thanks for help

Comment: @Chase : can you just help displaying stars next to values that are significant (>0.5) and 2 stars next to value that are more significant(>0.7) ??

Answer (score 3):

See if this does what you want. There are almost certainly more efficient ways to go about doing this, but without any details about the structure of your data - it is a bit of a mind reader's game to know what it is you actually need. Having said that, this seems to do what you want assuming the data comes from a data.frame:

```
require(xtable)
#Sample data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(matrix(abs(rnorm(25)), ncol = 5
  , dimnames = list(letters[1:5], letters[1:5])))


xtable(apply(dat, c(1,2), function(x) 
    ifelse(x > .7, paste(round(x,3), "**", sep = ""), 
    ifelse(x > .5, paste(round(x,3), "*" , sep = ""),round(x,3)))
))
```

Produces:

```
% latex table generated in R 2.12.2 by xtable 1.5-6 package
% Tue Apr 12 21:23:31 2011
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rlllll}
  \hline
 & a & b & c & d & e \\ 
  \hline
a & 0.626* & 0.82** & 1.512** & 0.045 & 0.919** \\ 
  b & 0.184 & 0.487 & 0.39 & 0.016 & 0.782** \\ 
  c & 0.836** & 0.738** & 0.621* & 0.944** & 0.075 \\ 
  d & 1.595** & 0.576* & 2.215** & 0.821** & 1.989** \\ 
  e & 0.33 & 0.305 & 1.125** & 0.594* & 0.62* \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
>
```

Comment: @weblover - does this answer what you need?

Comment: thank you alot , that's exactly what i need , but i found that in large tables this will add a width and hide some data. is there a way to make specific background color based on the value(the same thing that you did but instead of a star , a specific background color) thanks in advance

Comment: @weblover - I think that is fundamentally a different question than what you originally asked. If my answer or @Jimmy's answer your question - I'd mark it as such for others who find this question in the future. As for changing background colors, the first google search for "change background of table latex" yields this post which seems to be what you are after: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1405/how-do-i-fill-table-cells-with-a-background-color. I don't have much experience with latex so can't be of much assistance.

Comment: thank you for help :) , i found another way to do this , i used geom_tile to plot only colors

Answer (score 1):

Use print.xtable from the xtable package. That will then allow you to specify the caption where you can put the text you want. Then to add a star you can just add a column:

```
require(xtable)
tbl$significance <- ifelse(tbl[,5] > .7, "*", "")
print.xtable(xtable(tbl), caption = "")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . but i when i tried the code , it's giving me an error on (Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2 strings out of 494019
 12 string characters out of 3143873
 48862 words of memory out of 3000000) , and btw i want the output to be as more than 1 line as mentioned in my post. thanks in advance